# Use a Recursive CTE with a window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data where I want to compute percentiles (on `n`) within a grouping variable (`Weekday`).  I can do this with a while loop but am trying to use a CTE.  When I try to convert to CTE I get:

> Input parameter of PERCENTILE_DISC function must be a constant.

How can I use a window function within a recursive CTE?

**Make a fake data set as a Temp Table**

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMP') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DROP TABLE ##TEMP END
;WITH cte_numbers(n, weekday) 
AS (
    SELECT 
        0, 
        DATENAME(DW, 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT    
        n + 1, 
        DATENAME(DW, n + 1)
    FROM    
        cte_numbers
    WHERE n < 1000

)

SELECT weekday, n INTO ##Temp
  FROM cte_numbers
  OPTION (maxrecursion 1000)

--  SELECT * FROM ##TEMP
```

**While loop solution**

```
DECLARE @PercentileLookup TABLE(
    [Weekday] VARCHAR(250),
    [Percentile] INT,
    [n] INT
)

DECLARE @p INT;
SET @p=0;
WHILE @p < 101
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @PercentileLookup 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        frm.[Weekday],
        @p as Percentile,
        PERCENTILE_DISC(CAST(@p AS FLOAT)/100) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY frm.[n]) OVER(PARTITION BY frm.[Weekday]) as n
    FROM ##Temp as frm

    SET @p = @p + 1;
END;

SELECT * FROM @PercentileLookup
ORDER BY Weekday, n, Percentile
```

**Attempt to use a recursive CTE and error message**

```
WITH PercentileLookup(Weekday, Percentile, n) AS (

    SELECT 
            frm.[Weekday],
            0,
            PERCENTILE_DISC(CAST(.0 AS FLOAT)/100) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY frm.[n]) OVER(PARTITION BY frm.[Weekday]) as n
        FROM ##Temp as frm

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
            frm.[Weekday],
            Percentile + 1,
            PERCENTILE_DISC(CAST(Percentile AS FLOAT)/100) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY frm.[n]) OVER(PARTITION BY frm.[Weekday]) as n
        FROM PercentileLookup as pl
        INNER JOIN ##Temp as frm ON frm.[Weekday] = pl.[Weekday] 
        WHERE Percentile <= 100
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM PercentileLookup


--Msg 8726, Level 16, State 1, Line 70
--Input parameter of PERCENTILE_DISC function must be a constant.

--Completion time: 2020-03-11T13:26:16.4701034-04:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a rCTE or (what *would* be better) a Tally. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states (and the error tells you) The first parameter **must** be a *literal*; a column's value isn't a literal, so cannot be used.

You *could* use a dynamic statement to do this, but it's not really ideal:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,0),0) AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,0),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + N'UNION' + @CRLF +
                           N'SELECT frm.[Weekday],'  + @CRLF +
                           N'       ' + FORMAT(T.I,'0') + N' AS Percentile,' + @CRLF +
                           N'       PERCENTILE_DISC(' + FORMAT(T.I/100,'0.00') + N') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY frm.[n]) OVER(PARTITION BY frm.[Weekday]) AS n' + @CRLF +
                           N'FROM ##Temp AS frm'
                    FROM Tally T
                    ORDER BY T.I
                    FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,9,N'') + @CRLF +
             N'ORDER BY Weekday, n, Percentile;'

--SELECT @SQL;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7989424493b81fd61a71063441d738d0)